# How do I submit a form by email using html?

Tags: html, forms, html-email

How do I submit a form by email using html?
Do I need another language beyond HTML?

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: str,
    success: function (msg) {
        // alert(msg); 
        if (msg == 'OK') {
            $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
            $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
            $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
            $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
            $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
            $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }
    }
});
return false;
});
```

It's a simple form, but I never made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need HTML if its a basic form, you can do it like this (general answer) Of course this is assuming you just need it to send the raw info in an email:

```html
<form action="mailto:emailaddresshere" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!--data could be names, emails etc.-->
  Data1:<input type="text" name="data1"><br>
  Data2:<input type="text" name="data2">
  <br>
  <!--on button press it connects to email-->
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Now mind this is raw data, making it pretty is the next step

Try looking at w3 schools info, they are super helpful when you are starting.

Comment: Okay, is that simple (feeling like a dumb, lol)? on JS nothing to chance? Do I need php or python to do anything else?

Comment: I felt super dumb on my first post, the worst feeling is the downvotes in the first couple weeks. Don't sweat it. You can do it in JS, PHP, Python and on and on. If you want to clean you would need a JS script. What is your main goal here?

Comment: capture customers for my business, it's still little, trying to grow up.

Comment: Only thing you might want is a simple JS script like this to ensure its a valid email:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_email_required